# Google Docs - Converting large docx file to Google doc in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm trying to upload a book of ~500 pages(docx format) on Google Drive in order to open it with Google Docs and apply an App Script.

In Google Drive I have checked the "Convert uploaded files to Google Docs editor format" option in Settings. Therefore, whenever I upload a docx, Google Drive tries to convert it to a Google Doc file. When I try to upload this ~550 pages file, I get an error: "**Upload failed**". No other details are given. However, if I upload this book in 2 parts(files that have less than 300 pages), the upload and the conversion works. I would like to find a solution which will result in a single file.

I have tried to open both parts separately in Google Docs and then copy the content of the second part at the end of the first document (which has 288 pages). Doing so, I got the following error message: "**Can't sync your changes. Please copy your recent edits, then revert your changes.**".

I got the same error when I tried to append to the first file the next chapter found in the 2nd part. This should result in a document that has more than 300 pages. I get the same error as above, that asks me to revert my changes.


Does anyone know if there's a limitation in what concerns the no of pages for a Google Doc document? Some limitation that has to be around 300? The size of the 500 pages file is around 2 Mb, so it does not exceed the 50 Mb maximum size limit.

Comment: Could you please share a copy of the file you are trying to convert, so that this behaviour can be reproduced and a solution can be found?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to share a copy of the book. However, I tried to create a different file of 424 pages with dummy data and I uploaded it on Google Drive. This file has the same problem. It cannot be opened with Google Docs. If I try to upload the first 350 pages the conversion works.
You can download the file from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1phyiGJ3E1ONtPnlYUznmE8s9sT08dwbL/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit of **1.02 million characters** in Google Docs, as you can see in [the official documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en).

Considering that a single page might have approximately ~3000 characters, it makes sense that the service stops working at around 300-something pages:

1.02 million / 3000 = **340 pages**

In order to double-check this, I tried creating a random Document using Apps Script and problems started appearing at 300-something pages. So unfortunately there is no other way around it. It doesn't have anything to do with the original file being a `docx`. The only way to work with this in Apps Script is to split your document into small enough parts.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Alright! This makes sense now. Thank you so much for clarifying this!
However, they should display these limitations in the error message. Throwing an “Upload failed” error is definitely not enough.